Flutter Web - Reload Web App Save Data From other page
im working on a flutter web app and im encourting an problem related to the reload of the web page, the navigation as two String requirements, one is the id that goes to the url and the other one is one list of the ids that is received from the previous page that we had been. The probelm that im facing is : when i reload the page the error that i receive is type null is not a subtype of type String, caused by the ListofIds that skips to null when i reload the page, how can i modify that?
